# How to use trigger between two tables in Oracle SQL?

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper

Imagine this two tables

```
CREATE TABLE A
(
    idA       smallint primary key,
    idP       smallint ,
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE P
(
    idP       smallint primary key,
    Type      char , (ex:A, B, C)
    ...
);
```

I would like to behaviour like if in table A doesnt have the same type as in table P, is not for example a worker

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER VERIFYTYPE 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON A 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF((SELECT tp.Type
      FROM P tp
      WHERE tp.idP=:new.idP)!='W')
      THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'That is not a worker');
    END IF;
END;
```

I believe somethin is wrong

Comment: Use VARCHAR2 instead of CHAR, it will make your life easier.  You need to tell us what "Something is wrong" means....error messages, wrong outcome???

Comment: What is it that you are trying to accomplish? Just from what you have here, it looks more like you want a foreign key constraint or check constraint instead of a trigger. Triggers are usually used when you need to insert, update, or delete data in 1..n other tables.

Comment: the problem is not the datatype, is the trigger, the outcome about my trigger is this: Error(5,7): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following..

Answer (score 1):

IN PL/SQL you need to select into a variable. But gmiley is correct, a foreign key or virtual column with an index is a better solution.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER VERIFYTYPE 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON A 
FOR EACH ROW
v_type CHAR(3);
BEGIN
SELECT tp.Type
INTO v_type
FROM P tp
WHERE tp.idP=:new.idP;

    IF v_type != 'W'
      THEN 
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'That is not a worker');
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: @user3157136 if this answers your question you could accept it

Answer (score 0):

You have to:

1. rename the column 'type' as this is a keyword and you'll get a lot of troubles when using it
2. add variable x to the declare section
3. use SELECT col INTO x construct
4. use x in the IF construct